# How to find the root of a file

Tags: .net, vb.net, file

I am trying to find the folder that my file is in so I can use it else where. I am using an openfiledialog. So, if the path of the file is "C:\test\test.text". I want to be able to get "c:\test" without the file how would i do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 Dim path as String = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName)
```

Comment: Beat me by a couple minutes :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the whole path, you can use Path.GetDirectoryName:

```
Dim filePath As String = Path.GetDirectoryName("C:\test")
```

That would return C:

Comment: Thanks for still placing you answer :) Vote up

Comment: Thanks for the vote up.  Be sure to accept @Henk's answer so he gets the reputation for it as well :)

Comment: I know, was planning on it, i want to do anything i can to help the people that help me!